# How to create symbolic link in Linux Server

Tags: linux

How to create symbolic link to /home directory in RHEL 6.1 server?
The result of `ls -l` should look like,

```
home---->/data/home
```

I tried `sudo ln -sf /data/home/ home/` but is not creating link as desired.

**Text copied from comment:**

`/home` exists before the link is created.

When I run `ln -sf /data/home /home` link is created under `/data/home/home---->/home`. We need link to be created like `/home--->/data/home`

Comment: Please [edit] your question andadd more details: Does `/home` exist before you try to create a link? What exactly means "is not creating link as desired"? Does the command `sudo ln -sf /data/home/ home/` print an error message? Does it create a link at a different location?

Comment: /home exists before the link is created. When I run 'ln -sf /data/home /home' link is created under /data/home/home---->/home. We need link to be created like /home--->/data/home

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't answer in comments. Please answer **all** requests for clarification in your question. Does the existing `/home` contain any files or subdirectories?

Comment: Also, please add to your question what you want to do with the existing `/home`. Will you delete it? Move it? Rename it?

Comment: Also, your sample `ln` command uses a relative path, so you need to either correct the command or specify in your question what the output of `pwd` is prior to creating the link.

Comment: Put the `sudo` down and step away: `sudo` is not a cure all for every problem. In most cases it will cause more harm that good. It does not fix user error.

Comment: What `ls` are you using? That output looks odd.

Comment: Check out `man ln`. It looks like you are getting the order of arguments wrong.

Comment: When you run `sudo ln -sf /data/home/ /home` with an existing directory `/home` I would expect that a link is created as `/home/home --> /data/home`. To replace the existing `/home` with a link you would need to remove (or rename) the existing `/home` before creating the link.